# How to get component from template method in ECS?

Tags: c++, templates, components, shared-ptr

I'm developing what is going to be an Entity Component System game engine, and I'm having trouble when it comes to retrieving a component from an entity.

Here's my implementation of an entity:

```
class Entity {
public:
    Entity(int l_id);

// ...

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> GetComponent() { // T = CRender, CInput, etc
    for (auto& component : m_components) {
        if (typeid(component.second.get()) == typeid(T*)) {
            return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(component.second);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

private:
    int m_id;
    std::string m_name;
    std::unordered_map<ComponentType, std::shared_ptr<Component>> m_components;
```

ComponentType is an enum class contained in the Component class. Components pointed to by entities are Component in static type, but CRender, CInput, etc., in dynamic type. That is, I have a bunch of components as children of the Component class.
Also, I'm keeping a handful of smart_pointers to each component in different classes. 
The idea of the code is to check every component in the map, and check the type of the pointer pointed to by the smart pointer

That GetComponent() method is what I'm trying to get working.
The objective here is to be able to retrieve any component (CRender for render component, etc.) by doing something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr renderComponent = entity.GetComponent<CRender>();
```

Having a hard time figuring out how to do it, as I'm storing components in a map, so that there can only be 1 component of each type.

What am I doing wrong? Also I would welcome any better implementation design ideas that you may have. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the problem here:

```
if (typeid(component.second.get()) == typeid(T*))
```

The main issue is that `typeid` when used with pointers will not get you the derived type like you are expecting. It’s going to give you the `typeid` of “pointer-to-Component”, so you will always be evaluating `typeid(pointer-to-Component) == typeid(pointer-to-DerivedComponent)`.

As for improvements, in your code you are not utilizing the lookup by key functionality of `std::map`. Instead of looping through the map, you could change your GetComponent function to a non template function that takes the enum value as a parameter and use that to perform the map lookup.

Since you originally wrote a template function, as an alternative, you might benefit from changing the key type of your map to `std::type_index`. This would allow you to do:

```
std::map<std::type_index, std::shared_ptr<Component>> components;

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> GetComponent() {
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(components[typeid(T)]);
}
```

And you should include logic to handle the case where the component is not found, like you do in your original code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried the implementation you suggest for templates, using std::type_index as the key to my map of components but it keeps returning null pointers every time. I wrote that exact code and added: if (m_componentsTest.find(typeid(T)) == m_componentsTest.end()) { return nullptr; }, never getting past this point. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you finding that you are returning nullptr as a result of the item not being in the map or is nullptr being returned from the result of dynamic_pointer_cast? If the latter, you should check to make sure your component classes are indeed polymorphic. Does the base component class have at least one virtual method?

Comment: GetComponent() returns nullptr when it checks to be true that "m_componentsTest.find(typeid(T)) == m_componentsTest.end()", before calling std::dynamic_pointer_cast. Using debugger I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong when inserting components in the map. What I do is:     std::shared_ptr<CInput> inputComponent(std::make_shared<CInput>());
    entity->addComponent(std::pair<std::type_index, std::shared_ptr<Component>>(typeid(ComponentType::Input), inputComponent));
addComponent() only calls std::unordered_map::insert to add new Key Value pair to the map.

Comment: It looks like the issue is using `typeid(ComponentType::Input)`. You mentioned ComponentType was an enum class so when you lookup by the derives type you actually want, you never find it. I think you should be using `typeid(CInput)` when inserting that component.

Comment: That was the error indeed, feeling quite silly that I didn't notice it. Game running great with std::shared_ptr<CInput> inputComponent = entity.first->GetComponent<CInput>(); working just fine! Thanks a lot for your help.